# Copy partitioned tables with the same partion time

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to copy a partitioned table in bigquery along with the partion times of each row. Is it possible to do this. The schema of source and destination table should be the same

Comment: Would this not be the answer to your question?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#copying_partitions

If not, can you clarify what you would need that isn't present with the linked docs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.